# Monte Carlo Simulations in list-columns in R and purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have the following single case Monte Carlo simulation:

```
runs <- 100000
sim <- rnorm(n=runs,mean = 0,sd=1)
summary(sim)
```

But I would like to do the above with `purrr` in a list column. For example if I had the following data.

```
a <- tribble(
~group, ~mean, ~sd,~n,
1,      10,  5,1e5,
2,      20,  6,1e5,
3,      30,  7,1e5)
```

How can I produce another column of say `1e5` `rnorms` per group. In the end I may want to make histograms or summary statistics off of that list column.

I have tried the following.

```
a %>% 
  pmap_df(rnorm)
```

But got the following error, which I did not understand.

> ```
> Error in .f(group = .l[[c(1L, i)]], mean = .l[[c(2L, i)]], sd = .l[[c(3L, : unused argument (group = .l[[c(1, i)]])
> ```

EDIT:
For some additional clarity I have mean successful at implementing what I want in lists, but not in data frames as follows:

```
mu <- list(10, 20, 30)
sigma <- list(5, 6, 7)
n <- list(1e5, 1e5, 1e5)

args2 <- list(mean = mu, sd = sigma, n = n)
args2 %>% 
  pmap(rnorm) %>% map(quantile)
```

where `quantile` is just an example of a function, maybe I would choose to do `mean` or `sd` at a latter date.

Comment: group is not an argument that rnorm takes what do you want to do with that?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I just want simulations or random normals per group. If I have to I can delete the colum